# No me devuelve la respuesta AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

Buenas tengo un formulario de registro en el cual rellenan los datos y a través de AJAX inserto los datos en la base de datos. Hasta ahí me funcionaba perfecto y me devolvia una respuesta en modo notificación con TOAST.

Pero al poner en el archivo que también lo envie por mail deja de funcionar la notificación pero si que inserta el registro. Paso a detallaros el código.

**AJAX**

```
$(function(){
 $("#formuploadajax1").on("submit", function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
   if (comprobar_dni($('#nif').val()) == false) {
   toastr["error"]("El DNI/NIF no es correcto!", "Mensaje");
   return;
 }
  var f = $(this);
  var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formuploadajax1"));
  formData.append("dato", "valor");
  //formData.append(f.attr("name"), $(this)[0].files[0]);
  $.ajax({
    url: "incluCuenta/insertar-cliente.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "html",
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
    })
    .done(function(res){
      if(res=="1"){
      toastr["info"]("Registro exitoso!", "Mensaje")
      setTimeout(function () {
      window.location.href = "login.php"; //will redirect to your blog page (an ex: blog.html)
     }, 1500); //will call the function after 2 secs
     }else{
       $("#mensaje").html(res);
       toastr["error"]("Utiliza otro usuario!", "Mensaje")
     }
     });
          });
      });
```

*Lo que me hace ahora es que me saca del (res) me saca el valor que está en "else"*

**Detallo el insertar-cliente.php**
*Es un poco largo tendrá scroll*

```
<?php
include "../conexion/conexion.php";

mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");
$results = 'SELECT * FROM Usuarios';
$rec = mysqli_query($mysqli, $results);

if ($rec === false) {
die('ERROR SQL: ' . htmlspecialchars(mysqli_error($mysqli)));
}
while ($results = mysqli_fetch_object($rec)) {

if(mb_strtolower($results->Username) == mb_strtolower($_POST['email'])) 
{

  die('<div class=\'form\'> 
     <div class="alert alert-danger" style="font-size: 14px;"><strong>¡Error!</strong> Este usuario ya esta en uso.</div>         
    </div>');
  }

}

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['email']);
$telefono = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['telefono']);
$movil = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['movil']);
$nif = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['nif']);
$direccion = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['direccion']);
$postal = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['postal']);
$poblacion = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['poblacion']);
$provincia = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['provincia']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['pass']);
$sexo = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['sexo']);
$fecha = date('y,m,d');

$results = "
INSERT INTO Usuarios (
    Fecha,
    Sexo,
    Nombre,
    Password,
    Username,
    Direccion,
    Postal,
    Poblacion,
    Provincia,
    Telefono,
    Movil,
    Dni,
    intestado
) VALUES (
    '$fecha',
    '$sexo',
    '$name',
    '$pass',
    '$email',
    '$direccion',
    '$postal',
    '$poblacion',
    '$provincia',
    '$telefono',
    '$movil',
    '$nif',
    '1'
  )
";
if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $results) === false) {
die('Error SQL: ' . htmlspecialchars(mysqli_error($mysqli)));
}
echo "1";

include "../plantillaEmail/template.php";
include "../PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php";
include "../PHPMailer/class.smtp.php";



$email_user = "usuario";
$email_password = "pass";
$the_subject = "Bienvenid@ $name";
$address_to = "$email";
$from_name = "Depildiodo";
$phpmailer = new PHPMailer();
$phpmailer->Username = $email_user;
$phpmailer->Password = $email_password; 
$phpmailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$phpmailer->Host = "mail.depildiodo.com"; // GMail
$phpmailer->Port = 465;
$phpmailer->IsSMTP(); // use SMTP
$phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$phpmailer->setFrom($phpmailer->Username,$from_name);
$phpmailer->AddAddress($address_to); // recipients email
$phpmailer->Subject = $the_subject; 
$phpmailer->Body = $body;
$phpmailer->IsHTML(true);
$phpmailer->Send();
?>
```

El problema es al añadir el `include "../plantillaEmail/template.php";` es poner esta linea que es la que me imprime la plantilla del mail y ya no me saca la notificación bien.

**El template.php**

```
<?php $body="aqui esta todo el contenido de la plantilla";?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya probaste con utilizar typeof en lugar de ==, es decir en el if puedes utilizar,
if(typeof res == 'number' && parseInt(res)==1) es probable que la respuesta no la esté arrojando con el formato adecuado, otra técnica es utilizar console.log(res); para que así desgloses los resultados.

tambien puedes ver con

```
  .done(function(res){
       res = parseInt(res.trim().replace(/\D+/g, ""));
       if(res==1){}
       else{}
   })
```

Es probable que no estés recibiendo la respuesta HTTP correctamente, debería ser 200

Comment: Buenas e probado en la consola y si me devuelve el "1". Tambien probe lo de  if(typeof res == 'number' && parseInt(res)==1) y tampoco funciona

Comment: Quizá con esto el codigo se extienda un poco pero intenta a ver:

.done(function(res){
res = parseInt(res.trim().replace(/\D+/g, ""));
if(res==1) Y el resto

Comment: Estupendo!!!! muchas gracias @Miguel Guevara

Comment: Modifica la repuesta y te la doy por valida!

Comment: Listo, ya modifiqué la respuesta.

Comment: Por otra parte estuve viendo tu codigo php y creo que los array pueden ser para ti una mejor opcion, te enviaré un ejemplo

Comment: Vale gracias! estudiare lo que me mandes gracias!

Answer (score 0):

```
//Indicas todos los campos que necesites por POST
$need = array(
    "name",
    "email",
    "telefono",
    "movil",
    "nif",
    "direccion",
    "postal",
    "poblacion",
    "provincia",
    "pass",
    "sexo",
    "fecha",
);
$var = array();
foreach ($need as $key) {
    /*En caso de que no tengas el campo por POST*/
    if (!empty($_POST[$key])) {
        switch ($key) {
            case 'name':
                return "Necesitas un nombre";
                break;
            /*
                Continuas las validaciones
            */
            default:
                # code...
                break;
        }
    }
    /*En caso de que el campo sea válido*/
    else{
        $var[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST[$key]);
    }
}
$fecha = date('y,m,d');
print_r($var);
```